# Howto split genericList items with delimiter?

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, generic-list

I cant figure out howto split items from my genericList to two seperate parts with delimiter option?

```
  List<string> fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Skip(4).ToList();
          foreach (var item in fileLines)
          {
            values = item.Split(' ');
            sList.Add(values[3].Substring(2).Trim());
          }
```

My sList looks like this:

```
10.5     5.5
7.2      2.5
-0.1     3.0
-1.1     3.3
```

and so on .......... totaly 8760 rows in my List. 
What I want to do is to split each row from the List to two seperate parts so I can count the min, max and average on thoose  values.
(each value is meant to represent the temperature, so double)
Any help would be appreciated !!! Thanx

Comment: Your question is unclear at the moment - do you just have the data in strings, for example? What value is each meant to represent (double, decimal?) Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: "to split each row in 2 parts" show example

Comment: Yes to split each row in 2 parts with delimiter "\t"

Comment: So now i understand what you have, show what you want

Comment: Sorry for unclear description at the beginning, As said I want to split the sList to 2 parts with 1 column in each so I can perform calculation and get the min, max and average value on each part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why don't you use this one

```
List<string> fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Skip(4).ToList();
      foreach (var item in fileLines)
      {
        values = item.Split(' ');
        string[] vl=values[3].Substring(2).Trim().Split('\t');
        sList1.Add(vl[0]);
        sList2.Add(vl[1]);
      }
```